# NextJS 13 - how to show a page, when it is completely loaded

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, next.js13

All.
I'm new to NextJS (Frontend) world and I'm practising some things.
How can I make the page to be shown only when everything is loaded (every http requests has a response etc.)
The case:
I'm using Magic link for authentication and I want to show the email/username of the logged user, but it takes some seconds to change the text in the NavBar from 'anonymous'(hardcoded) to the actual email from the magic link SDK.

Homepage - page.js

```
import Banner from "@/components/banner/banner";
import NavBar from "@/components/navbar/navbar";
import CardSections from "@/components/card-sections/card-sections";
import {getVideos} from "@/libs/videos";


// This function can be named anything
async function getVideosApi() {
  return getVideos()
}

export default async function Home() {
  const disneyVideos = await getVideosApi()

  return (
      <main className={'main'}>
        <NavBar/>
        <Banner title={'Titanic - the movie'} subTitle={'Sad story about Titanic'} imgUrl={'/static/titanic.webp'}/>
        <CardSections title={'Disney'} videos={disneyVideos}></CardSections>
      </main>
  )
}
```

NavBar component:

```
"use client"

import styles from "./navbar.module.css";
import {useRouter} from "next/navigation";
import Link from "next/link";
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {magic} from "@/app/login/magic-link";

export default function NavBar() {
  const [showDropdown, setShowDropdown] = useState(false)
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("anonymous")

  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getUsername() {
      try {
        const { email } = await magic.user.getMetadata();
        if (email) {
          console.log(email);
          setUsername(email);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error retrieving email:", error);
      }
    }
    getUsername();
  }, []);



  const handleOnClickHome = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    router.push('/')
  }

  const handleOnClickMyList = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    router.push('/browse/my-list')
  }

  const handleDropdown = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setShowDropdown(!showDropdown)
  }

  return (
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <div className={styles.wrapper}>
          <a className={styles.logoLink}>
            <div className={styles.logoWrapper}>Netflix</div>
          </a>

          <ul className={styles.navItems}>
            <li className={styles.navItem} onClick={handleOnClickHome}>Home</li>
            <li className={styles.navItem} onClick={handleOnClickMyList}>My List</li>
          </ul>
          <nav className={styles.navContainer}>
            <div>
              <button onClick={handleDropdown} className={styles.usernameBtn}>
                <p className={styles.username}>{username}</p>
              </button>
              {showDropdown && <div>
                <Link href={'/login'}>Sign In
                </Link>
              </div>
              }
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
  );
};
```

Magic link useage:

```
import {Magic} from 'magic-sdk';

const createMagic = (key) => {
  // We make sure that the window object is available
  // Then we create a new instance of Magic using a publishable key
  return typeof window !== 'undefined' && new Magic(key);
};

// Pass in your publishable key from your .env file
export const magic = createMagic("pk_live_*****");
```

A short video with demonstration - https://files.fm/f/94p8867sw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize a loading state in your component's state and Wrap your page content inside a conditional rendering based on the loading state.Update the loading state when all the necessary data has been fetched. Alternatively, you can also conditionally render your userName based on the loading state. Here's an example.

```js
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
return (
  <main className="main">
    {isLoading ? (
      <div>Loading...</div>
    ) : (
      <>
        <NavBar username={username} />
        <Banner title="Titanic - the movie" subTitle="Sad story about Titanic" imgUrl="/static/titanic.webp" />
        <CardSections title="Disney" videos={disneyVideos} />
      </>
    )}
  </main>
)

//update the loading state...
useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchData() {
    try {
      const { email } = await magic.user.getMetadata();
      if (email) {
        setUsername(email);
      }
      setIsLoading(false); // Set loading state to false when data has been fetched
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error retrieving email:", error);
      setIsLoading(false); // Set loading state to false even in case of an error
    }
  }
  fetchData();
}, []);
```